# Current conservation in Yang-Mills equations?

Tags: conservation-laws, gauge-theory, yang-mills

In electromagnetism, the equations of motion are
\begin{align}
dF &= 0 \\
*d*F &= J
\end{align}

From this, we can easily derive current conservation $d*J = 0$.

The Yang-Mills equations appear very similar to this
\begin{align}
d_DF &= 0 \\
*d_D*F &= J
\end{align}
where $d_D$ is the covariant exterior derivative.

So, can we derive an equation for conservation of current for $J$ here too?

Comment: No, because the resulting "conservation law" looks like $DJ=0$ and as this has additional terms when compared to $dJ$, Stokes' theorem cannot be used to turn this into a surface integral.

Comment: Yes, it is covariantly conserved $d_D \star J = 0$.

Comment: @Prahar It is not a conservation law, though.

Comment: @BenceRacskó - its a conservation law. You may not be able to use Stoke's theorem, but that's beside the point. You should think of it as a conservation law of the type $\nabla^\mu J_\mu = \rho$ where $\rho$ describes the flux going into or out of a region.

Comment: @Prahar I strongly disagree with that statement because there is no quantity whose conservation - even local conservation - can be associated to an equation of this form. Nonabelian Yang-Mills theory has no gauge-covariant conserved currents and no nontrivial conservation law can be associated to the local gauge symmetry. The situation is entirely analogous to energy-momentum in GR.

Comment: You added an extra label "gauge-covariant" and once you do that I completely agree with your statement. OP is not asking about such things. Just whether there is any sort of conservation law satisfied by the current and I argue that it satisfies a covariant conservation law which is standard terminology. It may not lead to any conserved quantity which requires one to use Stokes' theorem but that is a separate point.

Comment: @Prahar How do you show $d_D*J=0$? I can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to first show that $d_D^2 (\cdot) = [ F ,\cdot ]$. It then follows that $d_D \star J = d_D^2 \star F = F \wedge \star F - \star F \wedge F$. Next, you need to show that $F \wedge \star F = \star F \wedge F$ using which we find $d_D \star J = 0$.